# Product detail blank page

Tags: magento2, http-error-500

I updated my website to Magento 2.3.1, and thought everything was working. 
However the product detail pages all show a blank page, no errors are shown.

I have enabled error reporting in both bootstrap.php and index.php, magento mode is on developer.

The webpage can be found here:

https://quiltstoffen.nl/quiltstoffen-categorieen/grote-prints/black-multi-cats-purr-fect-together-w-metallic

All other pages work fine, how can I make sure I finally get an error on the page so I can debug it?

Answer (score 0):

In the vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Product/View.php on line 117 add a return statement so the prepareAndRender is skipped and you will see the actual error.